# Docker for Windows container connect to host in NAT mode (modern docker not boot2docker)

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine, docker-for-windows

Please note that this is NOT a dupe of previous questions that at first seem similar, at least that I could find.

I'm running Windows docker, recent version, trying to get a container to be able to connect to localhost for testing purposes. I have good reason to use NAT mode Virtualbox, to do things like avoid exposing the database to the larger network.

My setup process needs to be entirely automatic, which is another point for leaving VBox in NAT mode, and is intermediate in complexity.

My build process includes lines like this:

```
docker run --volumes-from mystore -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -p 15671:15671 -p 15670:15670 --name myrmyq -d myrmqimage
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --link mypg:mypg --link myrmq:myrmq --name myserver -d myserverimage
```

In order to allow the outside world to connect, it also does things like this:

```
vboxmanage controlvm "myvm" natpf1 "tcp-port15672,tcp,,15672,,15672" (not exact, this is from python script with lots of quotes)
```

Thanks to the NAT routing, this allows only specific ports on the computer to be accessed on whatever container I want from outside the computer, even though more are exposed (such as Postgres ports in another container). So far, so good: only the ports that I want are exposed to the outside world, and it works well!

Also, there's a service running on the machine that makes connections with the docker containers, so it's handy having all the -p ports exposed locally without having, say, the above-mentioned database exposed to the network.

Only, now I need to be able to allow software running like this in Docker to connect to a Django server running on localhost. Is there a way to do this without setting VBox's networking to bridge mode and throwing all the config out the window? If I have to do bridged, can it be done reliably in an automated fashion? Alternatively, as a work-around purely for testing, could I have it connect to another computer on my local network (i.e. my Macbook) running said server?

Thanks so much for help & guidance.

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you are trying to achieve here with this port forwarding and NAT routing. Using `vboxmanage` seems to defeat somewhat the purpose of Docker if you are coupling your solution to it when it seems you could use Docker itself. It's also not clear what you mean by "modern docker" (or why you have boot2docker tag if it isn't that) but I assume you mean a Linux install on a VirtualBox VM. One note - you can `-P` to publish all exposed ports to the Docker host.

Comment: I'm sorry. I want software in container to connect to server on localhost in NAT mode. Thought that was obvious. Will edit.

Comment: As far as boot2docker goes, it is still running on VirtualBox, so I tagged it

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this in the future,

since it was purely for testing, I added a bridge network adapter as a *third* interface, temporarily. It appears to be impossible with a pure NAT network.